# Riddle Number Four

Tags: riddle, cipher

Time for a more challenging encryption, seeing how riddle #3 was decrypted so easily. First, I must note that this encryption was inspired during a chess match I partook in. I call it the ENIGMA CIPHER, a more notable cipher for those of the old Opord Analytical community.

Now, the riddle below is encrypted, as mentioned before. To solve this riddle, you must decrypt the riddle and solve it correctly. I will note that this will NOT be an easy task, but if it stays unsolved for a while, I'll add a bounty.

> A4|A8C1|E3E5H5B6|E6G2D3G5D2|A8G8G8|B8E7D2|
>   H6A1B4C5H6E3|G7G3D2|H7H6G5E5|E3A1E7D3|H1E2H5D2|
>   F7F6A4A7E8|E1E2H8|B8A6|D6C5A8C8H1G7|E4F1E2D2|A8C1|C3 ???

Good luck to all.

Comment: Any update around here? Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

A few notes for a work in progress.
First observations :

> - It may look like we are facing some 8x8 grid-coding (A->H, 1->8)
>  - There are 2 'one-letter' words : A4 and C3.
>  - there is a repeating 'two-letters' word  : A8C1
>  - This word is associated each time with a one letter word.
>  - the last association is in reverse order, followed by a '?'
>  - there is another interesting word : A4G8G8, whose first letter is the same as the repeating 'two-letters' word, and the 2 following being the same

And a few not-matching avenues :

> - provided the underlying sentence is english...
>  - Since there are not so many choices for one letter words, I guess One of A4 and C3 is 'I'. The other might be 'A', but since it is associated with what looks like a   2-letters verb (A8C1), it may be a subject, thus, I am thinking about "U"...
>  - So A8C1 might be "IS", "DO" or "AM"... but since it would have to match 2 different one-letter subjects, I'd say it's "DO". The text would thus be something like "I DO.... DO U"?
>  - Thus, A8G8G8 would not match here, cause I don't see such a matching word here (but for the unlikely "dee")
>  - also, I don't see any 8x8 pattern so far matching all the letters I A4 D A8 O C1 U C3
>  - also, since you are mentionning enigma, I guess it's more of a commutating alphabet, but I still don't see the key to understand how it is performed

Here it is... maybe this will help others, but I am still on it anyway

Comment: Keep working on your theory. You may be getting closer than you assume!

Comment: well it's an 8x8 that looks like a chess board the OP referred to, so I guess some horse-step moves are needed...